# sensu-plugins-aws ec2-node do not use credential keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, plugins, handler, sensu

Trying to automate decommission in sensu of shuted\terminated instances in AWS via ec2_node handler in sensu-aws plugin. i dont have AIM role assigned to instance and dont have credential file with AWS access for sensu user. i want to use json config to include keys. handler-ec2_node.rb file have a template of json config:

```
  {
    "aws": {
      "access_key": "adsafdafda",
      "secret_key": "qwuieohajladsafhj23nm",
      "region": "us-east-1c"
    }
  }
```

I created such file in conf.d directory setting appropriate credentials but get an error:

> ```
> 'require_credentials': unable to sign request without credentials set (Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError).
> ```

Looks like sensu does not use my credentials. or this 'key:value' must be with another key, not access_key and secret_key but something like `secret_key_id` and secret_key_id. I have tried different ways to solve this problem but did not succeed. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Change region to us-east-1 and see if it goes through?

Comment: I have tried with region and without region.  
when i tried to use ~/.aws/credentials for sensu's server user without region and it worked but this is not what i want.

BTW using availability zone instead of region returns an error in sesnu log. i have figured that out already.

Comment: Did you remove the "c" from the region and then tried?

Comment: Switched to AIM role attached to instance. still did not find out why this issue happen and how to fix it. now faced with another error. ec2_handler do not decommission server at stopped\terminated statuses. well... some times it do decommission at once instance is stopped, other time it do not decommission them at all and i have more than 3 days terminated instance in sensu.